# Fill a table with multiple .txt files via cmd

Tags: mysql, cmd

txt files that i download from a FTP server and fill a table with this files automatically with a .bat file.
I can already download the files and add only one file to the table here is my code so far:

```
@echo off
color 17
cd C:/Users/Silvia/Documents/Roboto
rename *.txt actual.txt
cd "C:\Users\Silvia\Documents\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
mysql -h localhost -u root -ppass <C:\Users\Silvia\Documents\Roboto\crear.bat
pause
exit
```

And here is the crear.bat code:

```
use Operacion15;
create table db(PATENTE varchar(4), ADUANA varchar(3), PEDIMENTO varchar(7), RFC varchar(13));
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/Users/Silvia/Documents/Roboto/actual.txt"
INTO TABLE db
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
(PATENTE, ADUANA, PEDIMENTO, RFC);
```

How can i make a cicle to run in all the downloaded files?

ill appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Use `for /f`. See http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html for more information

Comment: ok i added the line: `for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do  set FileName=%%~na.txt`, but i cant use it in the crear.bat is there a way to use a variable on the SQL console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a first look how the `FOR /F` command works, start with next command typed in a command line window (you could use `Copy` and `Paste`:

```
for /F %G in ('dir /b "C:/Users/Silvia/Documents/Roboto\*.txt"') DO @echo %~fG
```

Then you could modify your code as follows:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
color 17

    rem download directory
set "_pathDownload=C:\Users\Silvia\Documents\Roboto"

set "_pathToCrear=%_pathDownload%"

    rem make sure a "backup_done" folder exists
set "_pathBackup=%_pathDownload%\backup_done"
md "%_pathBackup%\" 2>NUL

    rem working directory
set "_pathMySQLbin=C:\Users\Silvia\Documents\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
pushd "%_pathMySQLbin%"

    rem LOCAL INFILE: elicit from crear.bat
for /F "tokens=5*" %%G in (
          'type "%_pathToCrear%\crear.bat"^|FINDSTR INFILE'
    ) do ( 
            set "_fileActual=%%~G"
)
    rem main loop
for /F %%G in ('dir /b "%_pathDownload%\*.txt"') DO (

           rem remove ECHO from next three ECHO-ed lines as soon as debugged
           rem moreover: at same time, remove ^ ahead of < from mysql line
    ECHO copy /B /Y "%%~fG" "%_fileActual%"
    ECHO mysql -h localhost -u root -ppass ^<"%_pathToCrear%\crear.bat"
         rem (optional) backup file treated
    ECHO move /Y "%%~fG" "C:\Users\Silvia\Documents\Roboto\backup_done\"
    ECHO(
         rem previous ECHO( line: for ECHO-ed output only to make it easy to survey 
)
pause

exit
```

Note:

- `backup_done` folder: it's a sample name (as well as the path);
- doubled `%` percentage sign for using in a batch file (`%%G` instead of `%G`);
- items in a path are delimited with a `\` backslash sign;
- `echo copy …`, `echo mysql …` and `echo move …`: *operational* commands are `ECHO`ed for debugging purposes only (to see eventual script behaviour): remove all `echo` prefix no sooner than code debugged;
- there is a difference in path to the `actual.txt` file: `…\Silvia\…` in the batch file you have provided vs. `…/Garber/…` in the `crear.bat` code

**Edit**: code improved and commented

If your downloaded files allow to be *merged* before sending to `mysql`, then the *main loop* part in your script could be a bit more simple (with the only `mysql` call) as follows:

```
        rem
        rem include part of previous script here up to 'rem main loop'
        rem

        rem main loop 
        rem merge downloaded files
type nul > "%_fileActual%"
for /F %%G in ('dir /b "%_pathDownload%\*.txt"') DO (

           rem remove ECHO from next ECHO-ed lines as soon as debugged
           rem moreover: at same time, remove all ^ ahead of > from mysql line
      if /I "%%~fG"=="%_fileActual%" (
               rem no merge 
        ) else (
            ECHO type "%%~fG" ^>^> "%_fileActual%"
                 rem (optional) backup file treated
            ECHO move /Y "%%~fG" "C:\Users\Silvia\Documents\Roboto\backup_done\"
            ECHO(
    )

)
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppass <"%_pathToCrear%\crear.bat"

pause
exit
```

Comment: I been working on the code you posted, but still i don't understand what does the following loop do `rem LOCAL INFILE: elicit from crear.bat
for /F "tokens=5*" %%G in ('type "%_pathToCrear%\crear.bat"^|FINDSTR INFILE') do (set "_fileActual=%%~G")`

Comment: It's here because I didn't understand different paths `…/Garber/…` vs. `…\Silvia\…` in your original question. After your edit: `set "_fileActual=%_pathToCrear%\actual.txt"` should suffice.